# Create leads in Salesforce through REST API. How to assign assignmentruleHeader and emailHeader?

Tags: rest-api, rest, leads, assignment-rules

I am trying to add leads in salesforce through rest API.Code is in java. I have converted WSDL to jar files and added as reference in Eclipse which allow to access salesforce objects in java. PFB my code.

```
System.out.println("-------LEAD INSERT----------");

String url= baseUri + "/sobjects/Lead";

System.out.println("((((((("+ url);

JSONObject lead= new JSONObject();

lead.put("FirstName", "LeadCreate3");

lead.put("LastName","Test3");

lead.put("Company","ACME");

AssignmentRuleHeader_element arh=new AssignmentRuleHeader_element();

arh.setAssignmentRuleId("01Q28000000e0Ow");

System.out.println("\n JSON for lead record to be inserted:"+ lead.toString(1));

HttpClient clientObj= HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

HttpPost post= new HttpPost(url);

System.out.println("\n"+oauthHeader+ "|||||"+ prettyPrintHeader);

post.addHeader(oauthHeader);

post.addHeader(prettyPrintHeader);
```

I want to add assignmentruleheader and emailHeader but i'm not getting which object to associate these headers with? 
When im trying to add assignmentruleheader i cant add it as Java doesnt allow this object through package reference rather it has assignmentruleheader_element object.
Similar thing for emailheader as well i have only object EmailHeader_element.

Comment: These attributes need to be set on the request. What is your HttpPost, is it from Apache httpclient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, [Assignment Rule Header](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/headers_autoassign.htm) states:

> The Assignment Rule header is a request header applied when creating or updating Accounts, Cases, or Leads.

The field name and the value to be set on this header is provided in the documentation as below.

> **Field name**
>
> Sforce-Auto-Assign
>
> **Field values**
>
> - TRUE. Active assignment rules are applied for created or updated Accounts, Cases, or Leads.
> - FALSE. Active assignment rules are not applied for created or updated Accounts, Cases, or Leads.
> - Valid AssignmentRule ID. The given AssignmentRule is applied for created Accounts, Cases, or Leads.

So if you have a request object as `post` (I am not really sure which library you are using here), then you would like to set the assignment rule header as below:

`post.addHeader("Sforce-Auto-Assign”, “[the assignment id]");`

---

Looking at the documentation of REST headers, I don't see anything available for Email Header, its available only on SOAP but not on REST.

Comment: Thank you Jayant i got it working with below line.                           post.addHeader("Sforce-Auto-Assign","01Q28000000e0Ow");                                           Is there any way to add email header similary?

Comment: I haven’t come across email headers with REST API.